# nodemailer error - you have more than 100 message on queue

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodemailer

I have a node application running on an Apache Ubuntu server. I am sending email through the `nodemailer` Node module. It was working fine but now the moment I run the code it shows the following error:

```
{ [Error: Can't send mail - all recipients were rejected: 450 4.7.1  
  <abc@xyz-group.com>: Recipient address rejected: You have more than 100 
 messages     in queue, try later]
 code: 'EENVELOPE',
 response: '450 4.7.1 <abc@xyz-group.com>: Recipient address   
 rejected: You have more than 100 messages in queue, try later',
 responseCode: 450
}
```

Can someone please suggest a workaround?

Comment: Are you handling the error while making `.sendMail`? Please provide with your code as well as the conditions you are setting for the email.

Comment: The SMTP server that you're using is telling you what the problem is...

Comment: [Nk piRate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11497767) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67052327) saying "... Assuming the service is Gmail there is a limit of 100 recipient per message for solution check [https://nodemailer.com/usage/bulk-mail/](https://nodemailer.com/usage/bulk-mail/)"

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error as you are getting. But It is not the fault of your code. It's because of the host which you are using to send email. In my case the host is not sending any email and that's why I got this error. It is solved once my host starts sending emails.